# How do I loop this program in python?

Tags: python, loops

I cant stop it from reapeating itself I dont see where I went wrong, I have asked about on how to loop it properly but I can not find out how to.

```
pwok = 0
print ("You password must contain lower case and uppcase characters")
print ("It should also contain numbers as well")
pw = input("Please enter a password to test: ")
while pwok != 1:
     caps = sum(1 for c in pw if c.isupper())
     lower = sum(1 for c in pw if c.islower())
     nums = sum(1 for c in pw if c.isnumeric())

      scr = ['weak', 'medium', 'strong']
      r = [caps, lower, nums]


     if len(pw) < 6:
        print("This password is too short please Re-Enter another password") 
     elif len(pw) > 12:
        print("This password is too long please Re-Enter another password")
     else:
          pwok = 1

if caps >= 1:
     if lower >= 1:
          if nums >= 1:
               print(scr[1])
          elif nums < 1:
               print("your password is " + scr[1])
     elif lower < 1:
          print("your password strength is " + scr[1])
elif caps < 1:
     print("your password strength is " + scr[1])
if caps < 1:
     if lower < 1:
          if nums <1:
              print(scr[3])
```

Comment: what are u trying to achieve by this program

Comment: I am trying to make a password checker

Comment: First step - fix your indentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to move your input inside the loop. Use continue after the checking the password len to return to the start of the loop if the len is too short or too long.

Without using continue and moving input in the loop, if the password is too long or too short it will loop forever and all lines will be executed even `if the len pw < 6 or > 12` .

```
pwok = 0
print ("You password must contain lower case and uppcase characters")
print ("It should also contain numbers as well")

while True:
    pw = input("Please enter a password to test: ")
    if pwok ==1:
        break
    caps = sum(1 for c in pw if c.isupper())
    lower = sum(1 for c in pw if c.islower())
    nums = sum(1 for c in pw if c.isnumeric())

    scr = ['weak', 'medium', 'strong']
    r = [caps, lower, nums]


    if len(pw) < 6:
        print("This password is too short please Re-Enter another password")
        continue # if you don't use continue all lines will be executed even if len < 6
    elif len(pw) > 12:
        print("This password is too long please Re-Enter another password")
        continue  # if you don't use continue all lines will be executed even if len > 12

    else:
        pwok = 1

    if caps >= 1:
         if lower >= 1:
              if nums >= 1:
                   print(scr[1])
              elif nums < 1:
                   print("your password is " + scr[1])
         elif lower < 1:
              print("your password strength is " + scr[1])
    elif caps < 1:
         print("your password strength is " + scr[1])
    if caps < 1:
         if lower < 1:
              if nums <1:
                  print(scr[3])
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you never read in the password again. So if the password fails the first time, you will be stuck in the while loop forever. You should read the password in the while loop:

```
while pwok != 1:
    pw = input("Please enter a password to test: ")
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import re
pwok = 0
print ("You password must contain lower case and uppcase characters")
print ("It should also contain numbers as well")

while pwok != 1:
    pw = raw_input("Please enter a password to test:")
    caps = sum(1 for c in pw if c.isupper())
    lower = sum(1 for c in pw if c.islower())
    nums = len(re.search(r'\d+', pw).group())
    scr = ['weak', 'medium', 'strong']
    r = [caps, lower, nums]


    if len(pw) < 6:
        print("This password is too short please Re-Enter another password") 
    elif len(pw) > 12:
        print("This password is too long please Re-Enter another password")
    else:
          pwok = 1

if caps >= 1:
    if lower >= 1:
        if nums >= 1:
               print(scr[1])
        elif nums < 1:
               print("your password is " + scr[1])
    elif lower < 1:
          print("your password strength is " + scr[1])
elif caps < 1:
     print("your password strength is " + scr[1])
if caps < 1:
     if lower < 1:
          if nums <1:
              print(scr[3])
```